# How can we achieve the below output (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to calculate the Numerator and Denominator values for one metric called Payments% and the formulae for numerator is count(distinct id) where menuaction in ('Billpayment', Renewal')

Denominator formulae is count(distinct id) and I need the below columns in output using postgresql database.

```
id,name,age,menuaction,'Payments%' as metric,numerator,denominator
```

Table Date:

[image]

Can someone please help on this scenario

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your desired results based on this sample data as well. It doesn't make much sense to output all of these columns but also an aggregate of the rows. Perhaps a window function is the direction you are headed, but it's not clear.

Comment: Just little confused to explain the scenario, But let me share my query so that may be you will understand . When I m running the 2 different queries individually for numerator and denominator and doing sum on top of that it is giving correct values. I need to merge these 2 queries with numerator and denominator in that and when I execute the sum(numerator)/sum(denominator) it should give the same values. Below is my query...Sorry If im missing anything very much new to DB.

Comment: Numerator:where menuaction in ('Billpayment','Renewal') : 
select sum(numerator)
from 
(select 
id,
start_date_utc,
date_interval as dintervalstartutc,
menuaction,
'%Payment' as  metric,
count(distinct id) numerator
from 
test_final
where date_interval::Date>='2021-01-01' and menuaction in ('Billpayment','Renewal')
group by 
id,start_date_utc, date_interval as dintervalstartutc, menuaction) b Output 746:

Comment: Denominator:
select sum(denominator) from 
(
select 
id,
start_date_utc,
date_interval as dintervalstartutc,
menuaction,
'%Payment' as  metric,
count(distinct id) denominator
from 
test_final
where date_interval::Date>='2021-01-01' 
group by 
id,
start_date_utc,
date_interval as dintervalstartutc,
menuaction) b

Output: 21069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `window` function would have been the right solution if `DISTINCT` had been implemented for it. Then sub queries will help :

```
SELECT id, name, age, menuaction
     , a.numerator / b.denominator AS metric
     , a.numerator
     , b.denominator
  FROM table_Date
 CROSS JOIN 
     ( SELECT count(DISTINCT id) AS numerator
         FROM table_Date
        WHERE menuaction = 'Billpayment'
           OR menuaction = 'Renewal'
     ) AS a
 CROSS JOIN 
     ( SELECT count(DISTINCT id) AS denominator
         FROM table_Date
     ) AS b
```

Comment: Getting the below error ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions
  Position: 41

Comment: right, answer updated accordingly